# mysterious and strange error in double to float typecast vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, casting, double

Please look at the following data taken from VS2010 workspace from file **lkpyramid.cpp** at   line no 425 from OpenCV 2.4.2

```
(A12*b2 - A22*b1) * D            -0.0551553(87)159150693    double
(float)((A12*b2 - A22*b1) * D)   -0.0551553(89)         float
delta.x                          -0.0551553(89)         float


(A12*b2 - A22*b1) * D            -0.0564279(18)227904397    double
(float)((A12*b2 - A22*b1) * D)   -0.0564279(18)         float
delta.x                          -0.0564279(18)         float


(A12*b2 - A22*b1) * D            -0.0360617(69)124602773    double
(float)((A12*b2 - A22*b1) * D)   -0.0360617(67)         float
delta.x                          -0.0360617(67)         float
```

see how digits  87->89, 18->18, 69->67 are converting , but we don't know compiler is converting from double to float is it truncating or doing more than that.

now question is what is logic to convert from double to float